# Apache ModRewrite fail on one directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Apache Rewrite Problem

i'm moving parts of my site at 〔xahlee.org〕 to 〔wordyenglish.com〕. I have this in 〔.htaccess〕:

```
…
RewriteRule ^PageTwo_dir/Vocabulary_dir/(.*)$ http://wordyenglish.com/words/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^lit/(.*)$ http://wordyenglish.com/lit/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^lojban/(.*)$ http://wordyenglish.com/lojban/$1 [R=301,L]
…
```

everything works, except the dir starting at 〔lit/〕. The error is a redirect to 404 on the original domain.

no other lines contains “lit/”. There's no 〔.htaccess〕 in lit dir.

Turning on rewrite log:

```
RewriteLog "logs/xx-RewriteLog.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

doesn't seem allowed or doesn't work with my web hosting environment. When these lines are present, browser returns a server error on any page.

the problem occurs only with that one particular dir. Seems there's some magic with “lit/”. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the second line with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
RewriteRule ^lit/(.*)$ http://wordyenglish.com/lit/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also the rewrite log rules must go in httpd.conf or your vhost configuration, not in .htaccess.

Comment: thanks for the tip on the rewrite log line. Though, still didn't work. Same behavior as before.

Comment: OK but now you have logs :) Keep them at level 3 or 4 - should be more than sufficient. Paste the log and comment here if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

the problem went away with this:

• create a dir “lit”, create a file under it.
• access the file thru browser.
• delete the file and dir.
• now, the redirect suddenly works.

maybe some glitch on cache somewhere. Not sure exactly what's the cause. Other dirs that are removed didn't have this problem. Just this dir.